# How to set the language in render_to_string helper?

Tags: django, internationalization

From a save signal in Django I want to send an e-mail. The language of the email should be set based on the content being saved (it has a lang flag). How can I pass that language to Djangos render_to_string helper? I can only find language settings for RequestContexts, and there is no request or user available here.

Sincerely
Björn

Comment: I just encountered something similar when running a management script... solution was to add can_import_settings and run translation.activate(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE) after that.

Comment: `translation.activate` also worked for me (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9283987/)

Answer (score 13):

Answer based on [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates):

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils import translation

(...)

cur_language = translation.get_language()
try:
    translation.activate(some_language)
    text = render_to_string('email-confirmation.html')
finally:
    translation.activate(cur_language)
```

And quoting the documentation (emphasis mine):

> You can load a translation catalog, activate it and translate text to
>   language of your choice, **but remember to switch back to original**
>    **language**, as activating a translation catalog is done on per-thread
>   basis and such change will affect code running in the same thread.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, while trying to set LANGUAGE_CODE etc in a new Context object (as suggested in other answers) didn't.

Answer (score 11):

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates) I found this way nicer:

> To help write more concise code, there is also a context manager django.utils.translation.override() that stores the current language on enter and restores it on exit. With it, the above example becomes:

```
from django.utils import translation

def welcome_translated(language):
    with translation.override(language):
        return translation.ugettext('welcome')
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears as I can use translation.activate(some_lang) before every message I send. I'm not sure if this is efficient or not.

I see that it's possible to send a Context instance to render_to_string. If I can place the language setting in that context somehow, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a custom dictionnary to render_to_string

```
render_to_string(template_name, dictionary=None, context_instance=None)
```

the default context variable for LANGUAGES (seen in django/middlewares/context_processors.py) are :

```
context_extras['LANGUAGES'] = settings.LANGUAGES
context_extras['LANGUAGE_CODE'] = translation.get_language()
context_extras['LANGUAGE_BIDI'] = translation.get_language_bidi()
```

so maybe setting the LANGUAGE_CODE is enough :

```
render_to_string('email-confirmation.html', {'LANGUAGE_CODE':'en'})
```

your template should look like this :

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Welcome to our new webapp" %}
```

Of course you'll to deal with .po files but you should be aware of that (if not check [this](http://blog.revolunet.com/index.php/general/django-internationalisation-with-i18n))

Hope this helps.